# Find the index of maximum element in BST - C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I got an assignment - creating an array and finding the index of maximum element in the array.
I need to do it with Log(N) run-time so I made a binary tree function, which right know returns the value of maximum element.
I am trying to change to so it can return the index of the maximum element with no luck so far.

appreciate any kind of help.

the code is :

```
void max_value(int *a, int i, int n)
{

    int j, temp;
    temp = a[i];
    j = 2 * i;
    while (j <= n)
    {
        if (j < n && a[j + 1] > a[j])
            j = j + 1;
        if (temp > a[j])
            break;
        else if (temp <= a[j])
        {
            a[j / 2] = a[j];
            j = 2 * j;
        }
    }
    a[j / 2] = temp;
    return;
}
int Array_Search(int *a, int n) {


    int i;
    for (i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        max_value(a, i, n);
    }
    return a[1];

}
```

Comment: Have you tried [heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))?

Comment: @Neil No I haven't, I actually don't know what heap is. I'll read about it now.

Comment: You can implement it as a type of complete binary tree that is implicit on the array, as used in heapsort. One gets exactly that run-time.

Comment: *"creating an array and finding the index of maximum element in the array."* The process of creating an array takes O(n) time. If you keep track of the index of the maximum element during that process, then you can report the index of the maximum element in O(1) time after finishing the array. In other words, please post a [mcve].

Comment: Here is a reasonable article that will help [Heaps/Priority Queues Tutorials & Notes | Data Structures](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/trees/heapspriority-queues/tutorial/)